# Spring not seen environment variables from systemd service

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, systemd

I'm trying to run spring boot app with systemd service of ubuntu.
In my service file, I have ExecStart variable

`ExecStart=/bla/run.sh`

And variables:

```
Environment="DB_HOSTNAME=ip"
Environment="DB_PORT=5432"
...
```

(I have tried both variants: with and without braces)

My sh file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOSTNAME}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
sudo /usr/bin/java -jar bla.jar
```

Inside sh variables are available as well, but spring application does not deal with them. The same with the active profile variable.

I thought that the problem is about the scope of variables and I tried to pass them to another sh from the main one. But in another script they are available, so the problem only with spring app.

**Update**
Trick with export does not help

Comment: It seems like your SpringBoot app is not able to resolve placeholder because these are only in the parent process scope. Try exporting them(`Environment="export DB_HOSTNAME=ip"`) and run your app. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will helpful for somebody.
The main problem was using sudo for starting java app.
After removing sudo variables become available.